# PHP Regex - Append String To Words That Begin with "#' Character

Tags: php, regex

How would I go about using regex to add a static string to all words in another string that begin with the hash character?  For example, I have the following two variables:

```
$stringtoappend = "someuniqueID";
$mystring = ".someClass #someID #someOtherID";
```

After processing the string, I'd like to create the following string:

".someClass #someIDsomeuniqueID #someOtherIDsomeuniqueID";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your *strings* are common CSS names (alphanumeric + dash), use [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with the following regular expression:

```
preg_replace('/(#[\w-]+)/', '$1' . $stringtoappend, $mystring);
```

Comment: who not just adding # into brackets?

Comment: @genesis φ: Because that would match `abc#def`, too.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I bet it wouldn't

Comment: @genesis φ: Ah, OK, I thought you meant moving it from its current place inside the class. But what good would that do?